# FireFox.exe path as per the operating system

Tags: java, unix, firefox

How could we identify the installation path of firefox.exe using java code.

```
    accumulator = (accumulator) && (runCommand("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "-P PAX-PROFILE-1 %s", "google"));
    accumulator = (accumulator) && (runCommand("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "-P PAX-PROFILE-2 %s", "google"));
    accumulator = (accumulator) && (runCommand("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "-P PAX-PROFILE-3 %s", "google"));
```

Here I am passing windows complete firefox.exe path.

Right now i am executing these command in Java, using

```
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(parts);
```

Is there any way through which we can identify the location of

> firefox.exe

as per the *operating system.*

Comment: Must it be firefox? What about `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url)`?

Comment: seems like you need to access a specific Windows executable file on a mounted NTFS disk from within a unix system in java. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Do you even need the full path?  Have you tried executing `"firefox.exe"`?

Comment: @VGR Yes, it needs whole path otherwise error

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question as 'unix', on a Unix / Linux / MacOSX system, you can do this from the command line using the `which` command; e.g.

```
$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

So, to do the same in Java, you can use a `Process` to run that command, and read the output into a string.  It is also possible to do the same thing by reading the `$PATH` environment variable, splitting it, and checking each of the directories on the path to see if they contain a "firefox" executable.  (You could probably do the same thing on Windows).

BTW, executables on Unix / Linux / MacOSX do not have a ".exe" file suffix.  The ".exe" suffix is a Windows-ism.

Comment: I am running which firefox command using java.   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("which firefox") but it's not returning anything. any suggestion why?

Comment: Perhaps firefox is not installed.  Or it is installed, but not on the current user's `$PATH`.  What happens when you run `which firefox` from a command prompt?

Comment: Its showing No firefox in (/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/windows/system32:/c/windows:/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/c/windows/System32/Window..

Comment: Well that is the problem then.  Firefox has not been installed in any of the places that %PATH% is telling it to look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not java-specific. On unix systems (and DOS shells) the general contract of locating an executable is as follows:

1. get the PATH environment variable
2. split it by the path separator character
3. consider each split result as a directory
4. check whether it contains an executable file with the name you're looking for.

At least that's what's used on the CLI. Desktop environments may use separate application registries.